# Jquery Comments.js The given range isn't in document

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery `comments.js` plugin to create comments section. When i gave reply to an existing comment i am getting the following error:

> The given range isn't in document.

I don't know what I am missing.

I referred : http://viima.github.io/jquery-comments/

[image: error]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]